# Can't read an .avi file to matlab using VideoRead

Tags: matlab, avi

Code:

```
A = aviread('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');
```

Response:

```
Error using VideoReader/init (line 447)  
Failed to initialize internal resources.  

Error in VideoReader (line 132)  
            obj.init(fileName);  

Error in untitled (line 1)  
A = VideoReader('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');
```

Any suggestions?  I can't use aviread, as I get the response:

```
Error using aviread (line 148)  
Only uncompressed AVI movies can be read on UNIX.  

Error in untitled (line 1)  
A = aviread('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');
```

Comment: Thanks for edits.  I have a MacBook Air running OS X 10.8.5, if that matters.  The .avi files are all 25-50 MB.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? Can QuickTime open and play the file? AVI is a container format, not a codec – open the file with QuickTime and press command-i to get info and let us know what codec is used. Also, your question is a bit confusing. The first error message doesn't seem to match up with the code above it. You tried both `aviread` and `VideoReader`, right? The latter should be able read AVIs that QuickTime can play.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that while `VideoReader` supports compressed video, it doesn't support compressed video when run from Unix. If you use the (deprecated) `aviread`, it will give you this error message:

```
Error using aviread (line 147)
Only uncompressed AVI movies can be read on UNIX.
```

Fortunately, unix has good tools. You can use `ffmpeg`. On ubuntu linux, install with `apt-get install ffmpeg`, and on mac, if you have homebrew, then just `brew install ffmpeg`.

Then use `ffmpeg` to uncompress. Using the first reference I found on google (http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-121280.html), something like this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avs -an -vcodec rawvideo -y output.avi
```

I tried it myself, and the new file (say, `output.avi`) still doesn't work with `aviread` but now it does work with `VideoReader`. Easy!

Comment: This worked for me on Mac. With .avi file `VideoReader` was giving an error saying that `Failed to initialize internal resources`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this directly? -

```
A = VideoReader('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');
```

As far as I know `VideoReader` supports compressed videos as well. Take a look at it's documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html).

This will create `A` as a multimedia reader object, that is basically a structure and it holds data for all the frames, along with the information about the video, like frame rate, resolution, number of frames, etc.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317579/how-to-select-specific-frames-from-a-video-in-matlab) for some examples of frame specific processing and how to access different components of the reader object that includes metadata associated with the video.

Comment: I try that on matlab 64bit 2015b windws7 64bit, on videos that play fine on media player and vlc, and still matlab gives the error `Could not get file information`. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to read the .avi video file using `VideoReader` function than aviread. `VideoReader` function gives an object of video to work upon.